# How to make query api for email that I can find data email wise for different users using Node.js, Express.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Client-side code:

```
const [myInventory, setMyInventory] = useState([]);
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

useEffect(() => {
    const getMyInventory = async () => {
      const email = user?.email;
      console.log(email);
      const url = `http://localhost:5000/myInventory/?email=${email}`;
      try {
        await fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => setMyInventory(data))
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error?.message)
      }
    }
    getMyInventory();
  }, [user])
```

Server-side code:

```
     app.get('/myInventory/', async (req, res) => {
        const email = req.query.email;
        const query = { email: email };
        const cursor = inventoryCollection.find(query);
        const myInventory = await cursor.toArray();
        console.log(myInventory);
        res.send(myInventory);
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), to improve your experience on Stackoverflow next time. You should put your own research efforts into solving your problem, show what you have tried, and add a brief description of your efforts plus the actual code that you have written plus the precise problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using axios method

```
useEffect(() => {

    const getInventory = async () => {
      const email = user?.email;
      const url = `http://localhost:5000/myInventory?email=${email}`;

      const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
        }
      });
      setMyInventory(data);
    }
    getInventory();

  }, [user, myInventory])
```